# How can I delay the loading of Javascript and CSS on my main page. Can I do it something like Google does with Analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a login screen that I would like to have startup as soon as possible. I am not using jQuery on that screen and I only have a startup.css file that I need.

On the second screen I need the jQuery and the additional CSS.

I am looking at the following. Would doing something like this be a good way to delay the loading of the jQuery and CSS from slowing up the loading of the first page? Is there another alternative to this using "modern" browsers ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxx']);
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
   (function () {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: You use a CMS or just plain HTML site ?

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple I guess. On your second screen HTML file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="secondCSS.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='secondScript.js'></script>
```

However, I don't think that's a good idea. It means the user gonna need to download more files than needed.

Comment: Why are you using single quotes in CSS and adding redundant `type` attributes here? CSS and JS are default types for stylesheets and scripts in HTML.

Comment: According to HTML4 specs, the type attribute is required. It's ok in HTML5, but as we don't know what doctype is used here, better safe than sorry. http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3 // http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT

Comment: My first screen has a login window. I expect a user will be there a few seconds or longer entering login details. I was hoping to be able to load the other scripts and CSS during that time so they were already downloaded when the user goes to the second screen.